# Blocked on connecting to Amazon RDS

Tags: java, database, jdbc, amazon-web-services, relational-database

I have recently deployed a DB Instance on Amazon RDS and I am trying to get the hang of it. After following the instructions on the documentation I tried connecting to that DB Instance but for some reason my simple program which shows the server's version hangs on the connection.

**Here is my code:**

```
import java.sql.*;

public class AWSTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getVersion());
    }

    public static String getVersion() {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Driver Error: " + e.getMessage());
            return VERSION_NOT_FOUND;
        }

        System.out.println(CONNECTING_MESSAGE);
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,
                USER,
                PASS);
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();) {

            System.out.println("Getting server version...");
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(VERSION_QUERY);) {
                rs.next();
                return rs.getString(1);
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("SQL Error: " + se.getErrorCode() + " "
                    + se.getMessage());
            return VERSION_NOT_FOUND;
        }
    }


    static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://**************.*******."
            + "*******.rds.amazonaws.com:3306";

    private static final String VERSION_QUERY = "Select VERSION()";
    static final String USER = "*******";
    static final String PASS = "*******";
    private static final String VERSION_NOT_FOUND = "Version was not found";

    public static final String GETTING_DRIVER_MESSAGE = "Getting driver...";
    public static final String CONNECTING_MESSAGE = "Connecting to server...";
}
```

My program hangs at the line `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);` and my main problem is that it does not even throw an exception, it just stays there.

`USER`, `PASS` and `DB_URL` are definitely correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your ip/port is getting blocked/dropped.  That's typically the case when a connection does nothing (as opposed to getting refused or failed login).  Make sure your Security Group is set up properly.  http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#31

Comment: I did setup my security group and forwarded my port before but I will try it again just in case.

Comment: What do you mean my "forwarded my port"?  You shouldn't have to do any port forwarding  for this.  Are you connecting from outside of AWS?  If so, make sure you're using your public IP in the security group.

Comment: I made a port forward on my router just in case. I think it's getting blocked because I have dynamic IP address so I will try to use my DNS to see if that works.

Comment: Dynamic IP is fine (but not secure).  Just go to an IP address reflection site like http://whatsmyip.net/ and use the address it tells you.

Comment: That was it, my IP in the security group changed by the time I used it so using the option "Anywhere" or just putting my DNS address worked.

Comment: By the way I have Dynamic IP because that's the default type of IP in Greece while Static IP is a premium which we pay for.